# Multiple development app settings in ASP.NET Core Web Apps

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, appsettings

I have an understanding question about ASP.NET Core Web Apps and the development environment.
Is there a way to have multiple appsetings in development mode? For example appsettings.Development.json and appsettings.Development.Linux.json.
The problem is that appsettings.Development.json holds Windows-specific settings and appsettings.Development.Linux.json holds Linux-specific settings. If I enter "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development.Linux" in the launchSettings, the development mode no longer works properly and I get error messages that static files can no longer be loaded, e.g. "_content/..." is not found at all, which is only physically exists in the Released Version. At least that's how I understood it until now.
So maybe there is a way to enable development mode programmatically and independently of ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT? Or am I doing something completely wrong and should I proceed differently?

My launchSetting.json looks like:

```
{
    "iisSettings": {
        "windowsAuthentication": false,
        "anonymousAuthentication": true,
        "iisExpress": {
            "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:8691",
            "sslPort": 44311
        }
    },
    "profiles": {
        "Kestrel Dev Blazor": {
            "commandName": "Project",
            "launchBrowser": true,
            "launchUrl": "https://localhost:6501",
            "environmentVariables": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
            "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:6501;http://localhost:6500"
        },
        "Development.Linux : WSL 2": {
            "commandName": "WSL",
            "launchBrowser": true,
            "launchUrl": "https://localhost:6501",
            "environmentVariables": {
                "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "https://localhost:6501;http://localhost:6500",
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development.Linux",
                "LD_LIBRARY_PATH": "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:[PATH_TO_64BIT_LIBS]:[PATH_TO_32BIT_LIBS]",
                "LD_PRELOAD": "[PATH_TO_PRELOAD_LIBS]"
            },
            "distributionName": "Ubuntu"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah don't use `.` or other special characters for that. I'd have `appsettings.LocalWindows.json` and `appsettings.LocalLinux.json`, with environment names equal to those.

Comment: The `.` is not the problem and works well. But while debug sessions the application works partiell not as expected. Also when i remove the dot i have the problem that the apllication will not found any static files. The development mode is bind to the word `Development`.

Comment: There's nothing hard-coded about the file settings name. `appsettings.json` is just a default. So is `appsettings.{env}.json` where `env` takes its value from an enumeration calculated from a specific environment variable. You could add your own optional file with `AddJson` and a file based on some other environment variable. You could use string interpolation to construct that path, eg `AddJson($"appsettings.{myProfile}.{os}.json")`, where `myProfile` may come from a specific environment variable and `os` from the current OS

Comment: Okay, that's what I feared. Would have been nice if you could say something like `UseAsDevelopmentMode("Development.Linux")` when configuring the app. But if that doesn't work, that's the way it is. Thanks very much!